# jQuery Deferreds for ajax template loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/FredyC/3pynD/2/ although not fully functional yet, i am not sure how to use jsfiddle echo service correctly with jQuery.

However point is, that when i run this, than `dfd` object doesn't have the `resolve` function. My goal is to have function, that will always return promise object where i can through `done` function get compiled template. When i want that template again later, it should return same `dfd` so i get template right away without fetching and compiling it again.

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's solved. After rereading documentation i had understand that `$.when` is returning just `promise`, so i cannot `resolve` it. So i created new `Deferred` object and it works like a magic :)

Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/FredyC/3pynD/3/